# Why am I getting this JSONDecodeError?

Tags: python, json

I am using the code below to submit an XHR request to a website and return the nested list the data I desire is contained within:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stagestatfeed/9155/stageteams/'
url = str(''.join(url[0:3]))
params = {
            'against': '0',            
            'field': '0',
            'teamId': '-1',
            'type': '8'
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

responser = responser.json()
print responser
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

```
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 7 (char 6)
```

The item being returned appears to be JSON, so I am not sure why I am receiving this error.

Can anyone be of assistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate that it is really JSON, since it's probably not. JSONlint will tell you where exactly the error is. I applied this "analysis" below the line (don't read any further if you want to find the solution by yourself from here on):

---

The returned JSON is invalid, because it uses single quotes for strings. JSON only allows double quotes:

[image: JSON string]

Replacing all `'` with `"` works:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stagestatfeed/9155/stageteams/'
#url = str(''.join(url[0:3]))
params = {
            'against': '0',            
            'field': '0',
            'teamId': '-1',
            'type': '8'
            }

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'Host': 'www.whoscored.com',
           'Referer': 'http://www.whoscored.com/'}

responser = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

print json.loads(responser.text.replace("'", '"'))
```